# Attaching and uploading documents with a form

Tags: cognito-forms

The free version says you can attach and upload a document but when I put that on the form it tells me I need to upgrade to that to work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I figured it out

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) you can create forms that support uploading multiple files via drag and drop, etc. even on the free Individual plan.  However, you must be on at least the Pro plan to include these uploaded files as attachments to email notifications or to include a PDF copy of a submission with these emails.

For more details, please see the [Cognito Forms Pricing](https://www.cognitoforms.com/pricing) page.